# Що таке "малашка"?

Tags: значення-слів

Цікавить значення слова "малашка".

В [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/malashka) та [СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=49354&page=1555) не знайшла тлумачення.

> Тосі, тосі, тосі,
>   Де ходили — в гості.
>   Що їли — кашку
>   Що пили — *малашку*,
>   Кашка смачненька,
>   *Малашка* — ріденька.

Answer (score 4):

**Нульове**. Точну інформацію знайти дуже складно.

**Перше**. Цілком може бути, що "малашка" - це рима, яку вигадали на позначення будь-якого взагалі напою, щоб дитині було цікавіше їсти чи гратися. Тобто, слово, яке не має значення.

**Друге**. Може бути пов'язано з запозиченим грецьким словом μελας. Тоді "малашка" - означення мутної, брудної водички або просто напою.

[image]

**Третє**. В Росії є ріка Малашка, але це вже дуже сильна спекуляція. Може бути, що від неї пішло слово малашка на позначення води й розповсюдилося далеко за межі місцевостей, де вона тече.

Пан Саша в [коментарі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/%D0%A9%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0#comment7860_5073) додає ще кілька здогадок:

**Четверте**. Малашка --> Малажка --> [Малага](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=369) — сорт виноградного вина. Теоретично споріднено з будь-яким соком.

**П'яте**. [Малата](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=370) «страва з кукурудзяного борошна»; - запозичення з угорської мови; Може бути якась кукурудзяна юшка. Це підтверджується ще й поясненням [малаштевки](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=371), копистки для вимішування мамалиги (страва з кукурудзяного борошна).

**Шосте**. [Молот](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom3.pdf#page=504) — пивна гуща, бурякова маса, розварена м'якоть ягід для киселю, відходи солоду.

Пан Artemix у своєму [коментарі](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5069/%D0%A9%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0/5073?noredirect=1#comment7865_5073) додає ще одне,

**Сьоме**.  У тюркських мовах є явище редуплікації, коли для позначення групи схожих предметів слово повторюють, замінюючи першу літеру на "м", звідси походять "шашлик-машлик" (шашлик і таке інше), "культур-мультур" (культура і все що з нею пов'язане), або kitap-mitap (kitap турецькою "книга", kitap-mitap - книги та інша література). Може і кашка-малашка створена за подібним принципом,

пояснення.

І все ж повторюся: поки що остаточної відповіді в інтернеті не знайшов, про утворення цього слова саме в такому контексті дуже складно казати. Можна спробувати зрозуміти, де виник цей вірш, і аж тоді через найпоширеніший варіант значення слів з цим коренем на конкретній території зробити більш точне, але однаково **припущення**.

Comment: Ще можу додати версію: у тюркських мовах є явище редуплікації, коли для позначення групи схожих предметів слово повторюють, замінюючи першу літеру на "м", звідси походять "шашлик-машлик" (шашлик і таке інше), "культур-мультур" (культура і все що з нею пов'язане), або kitap-mitap (kitap турецькою "книга", kitap-mitap - книги та інша література). Може і кашка-малашка створена за подібним принципом.